# Why does ethyl methanoate boil after methyl ethanoate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, boiling-point, polarity

Ethyl methanoate boils at [54.3C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethyl_formate) but methyl ethanoate boils at [57C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methyl_acetate).

These two organic compounds have the same molecular mass. In fact, they're just made by swapping who is the acid and who is the alcohol. Thus I would suspect them to have the exact same boiling point. Yet one is higher than the other by an appreciable margin.

I tried to reason it as that the ethanoic acid of methyl ethanoate having a second carbon might make it more polar, but I can't see the polarity difference.

Comment: Visual comparison of structures of $\ce{H-CO-O-CH2CH3}$ and $\ce{CH3-CO-O-CH3}$ suggests formyl differs to acetyl and the former molecule has overall more polar character.

Comment: It seems you mixed it up - boiling point of the acetate is 2 °C higher than of the formate... Not that it matters - bothering to rationalise such negligible difference is a waste of time.

Comment: @Poutnik Thanks, but can you elaborate why the former has a more polar character? I'm not seeing it

Comment: Polar groups at one end. But was rather speculation than statement. As the b.p. order is the opposite than originally stated, you may as well forget it, as overall effects go the opposite way and I was probably wrong. Similarly, acetone $\ce{CH3-CO-CH3}$ b.p. 56 °C is higher than for n-propanal $\ce{CH3-CH2-CO-H}$ b.p. 46-50 °C // BTW the same b.p of isomers, based solely on the same molar mass and composition, is unjustified. It happens only incidentally, as intermolecular van der Waals forces between different molecules are different.

Answer (score 3):

A glance at the molecular formula is insufficient to explain something like a 2º difference in boiling points, or the corresponding (slight) difference in room temperature vapor pressures (173 mm vs 200 mm at 20 C), or the flash points (-10 C and -20 C), which are again related to the difference in boiling points or vapor pressure.

A difference in polarity, or polarizability, might be able to explain the difference, if we are able to assign polarities - but that needs some sort of quantification. One way would be to compare solubilities: ethyl formate is soluble in water (a polar solvent) to 9%, while methyl acetate is soluble to 25% (Wikipedia). This suggests that methyl acetate is more polar, and should therefore have a tighter bonding situation in the liquid. So polarity does seem to be a reasonable explanation.

Another way to examine the bonding of the molecules together in the liquid is to note that the two compounds have the exact same molecular weight, but significantly different (i.e., measurable) densities: EtOCHO has rho = 0.917, while CH<sub>3</sub>CO(OCH<sub>3</sub>) has rho = 0.932, a 1.6% difference. My conclusion is that when two oxygens, five hydrogens and three carbons are combined into methyl acetate, they pack tighter than if combined into ethyl formate. If they pack tighter, they would be more tightly bonded, and so would have less vapor pressure.

After going thru all this, I'm surprised there isn't a greater difference in the boiling points!